# weird echo behaviour when printing one var at a time vs multiple vars

Tags: bash

I have the following simple code which I am hoping to convert into a for loop:

```
i="1"; \
plate="$(grep -P "^${i}" SampleIDs-Nov9-gyrA_S1-2.tab | cut -f 2)"; \
plateid="$(grep -P "^${i}" SampleIDs-Nov9-gyrA_S1-2.tab | cut -f 3)"; \
strain="$(grep -P "^${i}" SampleIDs-Nov9-gyrA_S1-2.tab | cut -f 4)"; \
replicate="$(grep -P "^${i}" SampleIDs-Nov9-gyrA_S1-2.tab | cut -f 5)"; \
timepoint="$(grep -P "^${i}" SampleIDs-Nov9-gyrA_S1-2.tab | cut -f 6)"; \
medium="$(grep -P "^${i}" SampleIDs-Nov9-gyrA_S1-2.tab | cut -f 7)"; \
total="$(awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{n=0}{ n++ }END{print n/4}' ../trial1_merged_dir/${i}.extendedFrags.fastq)"; \

mut="$(grep -P "^${strain}" mutants-short.unix.txt | awk '{print toupper($2)}')"; \
wt="$(grep -P "^${strain}" mutants-short.unix.txt | awk '{print toupper($3)}')"; \

mutc="$(grep -c $mut ../trial1_merged_dir/${i}.extendedFrags.fastq)"; \
wtc="$(grep -c $wt ../trial1_merged_dir/${i}.extendedFrags.fastq)"; \

echo $i; \
echo $strain; \
echo $medium; \
echo $replicate; \
echo $timepoint; \
echo $wtc; \
echo $mutc; \
echo $total; \
```

Output:

```
1
cip1
M9_Glucose
1
T0
4794
2938
9289
```

This is normal. However, when I replace the last 8 lines of echo with one:

```
echo "$strain $i $medium $replicate $timepoint $wtc $mutc $total"; \
```

Output:

```
 1 T0 4794 2938 9289
```

Not normal. I wonder what could be causing some values to dispensary?

Another time I tried it I got this output:

```
1   1ip1    T0_Gluco4794    2938    9289
```

Even more bizarre as some text fused and got truncated.

Comment: What's with all the backslashes?

Comment: The `; \ ` at the end of lines doesn't make any sense. `\ ` at the end of the line tells the shell that the next line is a continuation of this one, but `;` essentially mans to treat what follows as a separate line. They cancel each other out! Just leave them both off. Also, you should almost always put double-quotes around variable references, as in `grep -c "$mut"` and `echo "$i"`. I always recommend [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) to beginning scripters, since it'll point out common mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$medium` has a CR at the end. Either remove it after extracting the variable or preprocess the file with `dos2unix`.